Ignoring properties at runtime in .NET Core / EF Core and OData
I want to make Common.Student and xyzProp dynamic (replaced programmatically).
I have them as string right now how to handle type? I tried using generics and reflections but got an error:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true'

Any other approaches/solutions for this problem?
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
var entity = builder.EntityType<Common.Student>();
entity.Ignore(x => x.xyzProp);

